# How to prove that every real skew-symmetric matrix is congruent to a block diagonal matrix by using bilinear forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, bilinear-form, skew-mapping

> For any real $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrix $A,$ show there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $$PAP^T = \begin{pmatrix}{}
> \Lambda_1 &   \\
> & \Lambda_2 & \\
> & & \ddots & \\
> & & & \Lambda_\frac{n}{2}
> \end{pmatrix},$$
> where $\Lambda_i = \begin{pmatrix}{}
> 0 & \lambda_i  \\
> -\lambda_i & 0 \\
> \end{pmatrix}$, $\lambda_i \geq 0.$

I have found a decent proof of the above, but unfortunately it uses notions of linear (skew) transformations. I am having difficulty locating a proof that uses bilinear forms instead and I would like to try and understand that approach.

Comment: I think it very likely that the algorithm I asked about at link below can be adapted to skew symmetric  matrices, with all matrix entires used rational, if the original is rational. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr   I would not expect to finish such a computer program today. The one for symmetric (integer) matrices took me six months, on and off.

Comment: Oh, you want orthogonal.....If you can prove that, I cannot do any better. My change of variable matrices are determinant $\pm 1,$ but definitely not orthogonal. The whole point of that method is to keep all numbers used in the smallest field containing the entries of the beginning matrix.

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1682385/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719021/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388750/96384.

Comment: Hi Abdul! Where did you find the proof using linear (skew) transformations? How exactly does one find this matrix P?