# Conjugation of skew-symmetric integer matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, group-actions, symplectic-linear-algebra

In this thread [Congruence of invertible skew symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388750/congruence-of-invertible-skew-symmetric-matrices) it is stated that, for any invertible skew-symmetric matrix $G$, there is an invertible matrix $A$ such that
\begin{align*}
A^\intercal G A = \Omega :=  \left( \begin{array}{c|c}
0 & I \\
\hline
-I & 0
\end{array} \right).
\end{align*}

> If we assume that $G$ is skew-symmetric and belongs to $SL_{2n}(\mathbb{Z})$, is it then possible to find such an $A \in GL_{2n}(\mathbb{Z})$? Phrased differently, is the action 
>   \begin{align*}
> GL_{2n}(\mathbb{Z}) \curvearrowright \lbrace X \in SL_{2n}(\mathbb{Z}) : \text{$X$ is skew-symmetric} \rbrace, \quad g.X = g^\intercal X g
> \end{align*}
>
> transitive?